# Playstore remove my app due to Deceptive Ads policy

Tags: android, google-play

I developed a specific bookstore app that contains some books due to books are a lot of& we know Play store normally does not allow an app with a size of greater than 150MB
I divided it into the 3 apps and linked them. From one app, we can open two others by clicking a button. if the app did not install yet it would give a reference to Play Store.
My apps were removed by the play store and they emailed me your apps contain **Deceptive Ads** that are not allowed in Play Store?

I added in the Play console my app contains Ads.
also, I changed my targeted audience to those over 18 old.
And again Play Store reject my
What should I do?